# Merge rows in Power Query to replace null values

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table where rows are duplicated and I need to merge these into one row.

[image: Example data]

[Download Example data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iu-WVZI3kXW4w4T54XR80WKOl9VqSWOm/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113415770014086720861&rtpof=true&sd=true)

In this example I have condensed it to January and February which I need to merge, in my actual data there is one column for each month.

[image: Desired results]

I can do this in Excel but I would like to do it in Power Query instead, if possible?

So far I have tried to Group By and Transposing the rows but either I get an error or I end up back in the same results, one row per month.

Comment: I have tried to add the data as text but it gets very unreadable and not very useful, I am looking into how to share an example Excel file instead, just need to find a place to store the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your source data file.  It groups on a bunch of stuff, then fills up the month columns

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ContractNumber", "Year", "Quarter", "Product", "SerialNumber", "PersonFullName", "PersonCostCarrierCode", "CompanyName", "CompanyOrgNo","Cost"}, {{"data", each 
     Table.FirstN(Table.FillUp(        
     Table.SelectColumns(_,{"December", "November", "October", "September", "August", "June", "May", "April", "March", "February", "January"})
     ,{"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}),1)
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"December", "November", "October", "September", "August", "June", "May", "April", "March", "February", "January"}, {"December", "November", "October", "September", "August", "June", "May", "April", "March", "February", "January"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue, now there are no duplicate rows :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the [January] column on "January" and then replace all *null* values in the [February] column with "February" to get your expected result. All other data is duplicate anyhow, except for the MonthNr, but you are discarding that information.

Comment: The problem is that my data is roughly 40 000 rows and it contains different users, I will try to illustrate this in a new example file.

Comment: So you need some iterations to come up with your final question?

Comment: I guess my first example data was to narrow, this has now been rectified and a link is available to download the example data :-)

Comment: Note that questions on StackOverflow have to be self-contained and don't refer to external temporary resources that are likely no longer available for subsequent users interested in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this:

- Unpivot the "Months" columns

  - After doing this, the Attributes and Values columns will be identical, so delete one of them
- Group by the columns that define your "duplicate rows"
- in the Aggregation, create a Record of the months data:
  eg:  `{"Records", each Record.FromList([Month],[Month]), type record}`
- Then Expand that record column, using a List of the Months for the Column Names